# Java equivalent of GC.SuppressFinalize

Tags: java, .net, garbage-collection, finalizer

Does Java have an equivalent of .Net's [GC.SuppressFinalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx)?

In .Net, SuppressFinalize is used in the [dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid the [relatively high performance cost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx#dotnetgcbasics_topic5) of finalization as long as the object is explicitly disposed. Similar costs apply to Java, but it doesn't seem to have SuppressFinalize.

I know that generally it's better to simply avoid finalizers altogether, but I don't think I can avoid them for my particular use case (a cancel token where you can add handlers that run only if another token isn't cancelled first, so a token becoming immortal due to its source being collected must result in entries being removed from linked tokens lest they accumulate garbage entries without bound).

Is there an equivalent of SuppressFinalize in Java? If not, can it be approximated by using the available tools (e.g. [ReferenceQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html))?

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood Yes, Object has a [finalize method you can override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29).

Comment: there are some useful suggestion
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021609/how-to-handle-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-android-os-binderproxy-fin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native "GC.SuppressFinalize" method for Java. But IDiposable pattern will be useful for you to address this.

You can Manually dispose of an item when you know it is no longer needed or
Be able to run clean up code to safely bring down connections, close files, etc.Also you will
be able to use finalizer to catch situation where it is not known when an object should be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a possible workaround for there being no equivalent in Java, insofar as avoiding the cost of finalizers goes: use a cache.

1. Have an object with a changeable callback member:

   ```
   public final class Finalizer {
     public Runnable onFinalizer;
     @Override
     protected void finalize() {
       if (onFinalizer != null) {
         onFinalizer.run();
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Have a collection of them:

   ```
   Stack<Finalizer> finalizerCache = new Stack<>();
   ```
3. Grab when needed:

   ```
   this.finalizer = finalizerCache.isEmpty() ? new Finalizer() : finalizerCache.pop();
   this.finalizer.onFinalizer = () -> { my special cleanup code; };
   ```
4. Discard when needed:

   ```
   void cancel() {
     this.finalizer.onFinalizer = null;
     if (finalizerCache.size() < 100) {
       finalizerCache.push(this.finalizer);
     }
     this.finalizer = null;
   }
   ```

Obviously there can be a lot of tweaking related to the size of the cache and how it's synchronized, but this should be a useful way to avoid the cost of finalizers in cases where the finalizers only rarely run and there's not too much churn in the total number of objects requiring finalization.